# Can't post in wall/logout from facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

At the oficial facebook developers tutorial, they say posting in users Wall on facebook is as easy as writing this single line:

```
mFacebook.dialog(context, "feed", new PostDialogListener());
```

but when I try to use this, it keeps asking me to create the PostDialogListener class. Isn't that included with facebook sdk? where can I find this class?

and, to logout, I must use this:

```
mAsyncRunner.logout(getContext(), new RequestListener() {
@Override
public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {}

@Override
public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {}

@Override
public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
    Object state) {}

@Override
public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
    Object state) {}

@Override
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {}
});
```

And then I'm asked to create getContext() method.

Facebook's tutorial is very incomplete, what must I do now? Thanks!

Edit: My facebook activity is very simple, i just connect and retrieve data from user, then pass it to another activity. I wat to implement a logout method, and also ask user to post on wall after login (that would be in another activity)

```
public class FacebookConnectActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG_JSON = "json";
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("12121212112");
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
JSONObject json;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resgatar_produto_layout);


    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if(access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

    facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"email", "user_birthday",     "publish_actions"}, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}   
    });

    }

}

public void logoutFB(){

}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try{
        json = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me"));
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "JSON " + json.toString());
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "JSONException " + e.toString());
    }catch(FacebookError fbe){
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "FacebookError " + fbe.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "Exception " + e.toString());
    }

    Intent a = new Intent(FacebookConnectActivity.this, FacebookDataProcess.class);
    a.putExtra(TAG_JSON, json.toString());
    startActivity(a);
    finish();
}   
}
```

Comment: Facebooks tutorial is very complete, it is your understanding of Java and Android that is incomplete.  I have to say I followed the facebook API tutorials and got it working very quickly.  I suggest you read up on context, you look at where you are putting your code, how you are going about it, look at listeners and how to implement them etc.

Comment: "The Android SDK provides a method for displaying a Facebook Platform dialog, which allows you to enhance social distribution and provide basic Facebook functionality in your app with a singe line of code" I'm missing the "single line of code" part, but will give it another look. Maybe someone who completely understands Java and Android could help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've just got something that works:

in FacebookConnectActivity:

```
public static  void logoutFB(){
    if(facebook.isSessionValid()){
        facebook.setAccessToken(null);
    }
}
```

This method is called in a logoutbutton.onclick just like this:

```
FacebookConnectActivity.logoutFB();
```

Maybe it helps someone.

Comment: ps: need to declare facebook static